# sort a list in Erlang using List comprehension

Tags: list, erlang, list-comprehension

sortLC(List)-> [if L  < M -> L; true -> M end || L<-List,M<-List]
im trying to sort  a list 
using this method: List comprehension

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension are not meant for this usage. A generator produce all the elements of its list separately, if there are several generators, you get all the possible combinations from left to right

```
1> [{X,Y,Z} || X <- [1,2], Y <- [a,b], Z <- [y,z]].         
[{1,a,y},
 {1,a,z},
 {1,b,y},
 {1,b,z},
 {2,a,y},
 {2,a,z},
 {2,b,y},
 {2,b,z}]
```

As the generator are evaluated in that order, it is possible to reuse the value produced by a generator in an other one placed to the right:

```
2> F2 = fun(N) -> [{X,Y,Z} || X <- lists:seq(1,N-2), Y <- lists:seq(X+1,N-1), Z <- lists:seq(Y+1,N)] end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
3> F2(5).                                                                      
[{1,2,3},                 
 {1,2,4},
 {1,2,5},
 {1,3,4},
 {1,3,5},
 {1,4,5},
 {2,3,4},
 {2,3,5},
 {2,4,5},
 {3,4,5}]
```

Interesting to limit the number of cases. you can also add filters so only the n-uplets that match the conditions will be "generated":

```
4> F1 = fun(N) -> [{X,Y,Z} || X <- lists:seq(1,N-2), Y <- lists:seq(X+1,N-1), Z <- lists:seq(Y+1,N), X*X + Y*Y - Z*Z == 0] end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
5> F1(5).
[{3,4,5}]
```

Here you get all the combinations of 3 numbers such as X < Y < Z and X²+Y²-Z² == 0 :o)

of course it is possible to use the X,Y,Z elements as parameters of a function, in this case the parameter will be executed on each  combination, and you will collect the list of the results:

```
6> F = fun(N) -> [io:format("~w, ~w and ~w is a Pythagorean Triple~n",[X,Y,Z]) || X <- lists:seq(1,N-2), Y <- lists:seq(X+1,N-1), Z <- lists:seq(Y+1,N), X*X + Y*Y - Z*Z == 0] end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
7> F(20).
3, 4 and 5 is a Pythagorean Triple
5, 12 and 13 is a Pythagorean Triple
6, 8 and 10 is a Pythagorean Triple
8, 15 and 17 is a Pythagorean Triple
9, 12 and 15 is a Pythagorean Triple
12, 16 and 20 is a Pythagorean Triple
[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok]
```

AS you can see the usage is to make some evaluation for each combination, eventually filtered, but there is no built in concept of accumulation or construction of a single result.

Answer (score 0):

This won't really work. It looks like you don't understand Erlang semantics properly. Especially what the list comprehension does. Your solution returns the cartesian product of the lists. Try looking at the output of [{X, Y} || X <- L, Y <- L]. Which may hint you at what is happening. There are several ways of sorting a list through LC's. One is the following:

```
sort([]) -> [];
sort([E | Rest]) ->
    Less = [X || X <- Rest, X =< E],
    Greater = [X || X <- Rest, X > E],
    sort(Less) ++ [E] ++ sort(Greater).
```

(not tested). The idea is to partition the list into two halves. Those where the elements are less then the first element. And those where the elements are greater. This paritioning then sets up the recursive divide-and-conquer scheme like in Quicksort. To test for correctness, one can lift through the built-in sort function with PropEr/QuickCheck:

```
prop_sort() ->
  ?FORALL(L, list(int()),
     begin
         equal(lists:sort(L), sort(L))
     end).
```

Comment: i saw the quick sort algo , i was thinking if its possible without the recursive call , only use  List comprehension

Comment: It might be possible, but I am afraid you will have slow code as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [here](https://github.com/mkorszun/Erlgorithms/blob/master/src/sort.erl) if you are interested in popular sort algorithms (bubble, insertion, quick, merge) and their implementation in erlang.